# RDLC sorting on multiple columns

Tags: visual-studio, sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I want to sort an rdlc report by two or more columns.

This could happen if I have two names that are the same so then it should next be sorted by ID column.

When I navigate to textbox properties and click the interactive sort tab I can only select one column to sort by.

How to add more than one column?

EDIT: I just realised you can edit the matrix of the entire table to add multiple sort fields. I'm guessing you can also create a group and attach that to the column if needed.

Comment: this msdn link explains in details the solution by 'denzuchan' 

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251728(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also did not find multiple columns fields for interactive sorting. 
You can workaround this by specifying an expression where you concatenate columns values. Note that date field you have to format in a sort friendly way.

```
=Fields!MyString.Value & CDate(Fields!MyDate.Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really a cool workaround, however, what can I do if I want the the first "Fields!MyString.Value" column would be sorted ASCENDING and the second "Fields!MyDate.Value" column would be sorted DESCENDING?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can add multiple sort fields in the tablix properties.

Aside from that, if you click on a row textbox, you can see the *Interactive Sorting* tab, where you can group and sort field values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this msdn link explains in details the solution by 'denzuchan'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251728(v=vs.80).aspx